# Converts the configuration (text file) into a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have tried many time to convert this config file to multidimensional array, this mean I must be read config.txt file and then I must be convert to multidimensional array. I need help or some suggests.

config.txt:

```
id=www
session.timeout=120

session.server.0.host=127.0.0.1

session.server.0.port=1111

session.server.0.id=session1

session.server.1.host=127.0.0.1

session.server.1.port=1111

session.server.1.id=session2

image.width=640 

image.height=480 

image.watermark.small=wsmall.png 

image.watermark.normal=wnormal.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$config = array();
foreach( file( 'config.txt') as $line) {
    list( $keys, $value) = explode( '=', $line);

    $temp =& $config;
    foreach( explode( '.', $keys) as $key)
    {           
        $temp =& $temp[$key];
    }
    $temp = trim( $value);
}
```

After reading each line at a time, you get all of the keys into `$keys` and the value into `$value` by `explode()`-ing on `=`. Then, using `$temp` as a "pointer" to the `$config` array, I loop over all of the `$keys`, which are individually extracted by `explode()`-ing on `.`, to form the multidimensional array. Once all of the keys are used up, I assign the value to that entry, and move to the next line.

You can see it working quite nicely in [the demo](http://viper-7.com/mg63Zq). For your input, this will produce an array like this:

```
array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "www"
  ["session"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["timeout"]=>
    string(3) "120"
    ["server"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["host"]=>
        string(9) "127.0.0.1"
        ["port"]=>
        string(4) "1111"
        ["id"]=>
        string(8) "session1"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["host"]=>
        string(9) "127.0.0.1"
        ["port"]=>
        string(4) "1111"
        ["id"]=>
        string(8) "session2"
      }
    }
  }
  ["image"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["width"]=>
    string(3) "640"
    ["height"]=>
    string(3) "480"
    ["watermark"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["small"]=>
      string(10) "wsmall.png"
      ["normal"]=>
      &string(11) "wnormal.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function load_config_file($filename)
{
    $config = array();

    foreach(file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) as $line)
    {
        if(!preg_match('/^(.+?)=(.*)$/', $line, $matches))
        {
            continue;
        }
        $indices = explode('.', $matches[1]);
        $current = &$config;
        foreach($indices as $index)
        {
            $current = &$current[$index];
        }
        $current = $matches[2];
    }

    return $config;
}
```

Result of `load_config_file('config.txt')`:

```
Array
(
    [id] => www
    [session] => Array
        (
            [timeout] => 120
            [server] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [host] => 127.0.0.1
                            [port] => 1111
                            [id] => session1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [host] => 127.0.0.1
                            [port] => 1111
                            [id] => session2
                        )

                )

        )

    [image] => Array
        (
            [width] => 640
            [height] => 480
            [watermark] => Array
                (
                    [small] => wsmall.png
                    [normal] => wnormal.png
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com) has a class called [Zend_Config_Ini](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html) that will parse a file of this structure into an object or array.

In order to use it, you would need to take 3 files from the Zend Framework library:

- Zend/Config.php
- Zend/Config/Ini.php
- Zend/Config/Exception.php

Once you have those 3 files, here is code that demonstrates parsing and accessing values from that file:

```
require_once 'Zend/Config/Ini.php';

$ini = new Zend_Config_Ini('settings.ini');
$ini = $ini->toArray();

echo $ini['session']['server'][0]['host']; // 127.0.0.1
echo $ini['session']['server'][1]['id'];   // session2
echo $ini['image']['width'];               // 640
```

To get the 3 files from Zend Framework working, place them in a folder called `Zend` somewhere with your PHP files and add the directory that `Zend` is in to your [include_path](http://php.net/set_include_path).