# PHP Multi level dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

According to this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656159/converts-the-configuration-text-file-into-a-multidimensional-array) I wrote a similar answer as in bottom. Wonder if there is more generic and compact way of writing the solution?

```
$multi_d = array();
$read_conf = parse_ini_file($filename);
foreach( $read_conf as $keys => $value)
{
    $temp =& $multi_d;
    foreach(explode( '.', $keys) as $key)
        $temp =& $temp[$key];
    $temp = trim( $value);
}
```

Comment: Yes there is, but readability is a million times more important than compactness.

Comment: what about when there is a compilation time to take into consideration?

Comment: Compactness and speed of execution are unrelated. And the difference would be insignificant anyway.